# Microsoft Office Web Components IE Security Issue

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer, ms-office, components, web-parts

I am displaying Microsoft Office Web Components (Microsoft Data Access Controls) on my Sharepoint site. Clients need to enable "Access Data Sources Across Domains" in IE in order to view the page. Unfortunately, clients cannot modify their IE settings. Is there anyway I can get these components to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not these components, you may try to use other ways to diplay taht data, not using the Web components.
However, you could see if the users machines can be updated by a goup policy that will change te IE settings. In the following article is shown that is ok to have it enbled (with prompt):
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833633 - How to strengthen the security settings for the Local Machine zone in Internet Explorer

Comment: it is an IE security issue, and is designed to do that. no way to get around it i guess without changing group policy.

Answer (score 1):

Typically it is enough to register your SharePoint site with IE as a **trusted site** (or as a **local intranet** one).

You probably need to convince the clients admins to add a corresponding domain policy.

Comment: adding it as a trusted site/local intranet site does not alleviate the problem. seems like domain policy is the only way to go, which is going to be tough getting buy-in